# HTA(vbs) - To do list - delete or modify array items

Tags: vbscript, hta

I'm trying to create an HTA To Do List saving locally to a text file. Every time you press submit button generates a new entry that display inside hta body and it's being saved  inside the text file. I want to develop this furthermore :

1. delete an  entry and update body/text file
2. modify an entry and update body/text file
3. put new entry on top

Any suggestions?

```
     <html>
    <head>
    <HTA:APPLICATION SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" APPLICATIONNAME="To Do List">
    </head>

    <SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    Sub Window_OnLoad 
    ReadBlog
    End Sub 

        Sub SaveData
        strDel1="<"
        strDel2=">"
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            If objFSO.FileExists("C:\Test.txt") Then
               Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Test.txt", 8)
                strLine = strDel1 & Time & vbTab & Date & vbTab & Title.Value & vbTab & Message.Value & strDel2
                objFile.WriteLine strLine
                objFile.Close
            Else
                Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Test.txt")
                strLine = strDel1 & Time & vbTab & Date & vbTab & Title.Value & vbTab & Message.Value & strDel2
                objFile.WriteLine strLine
                objFile.Close
            End If

             ReadBlog
             ClearText
        End Sub

        Sub ReadBlog
        Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
         dim sampletext, objRegExp, SearchPattern, ReplacePattern, matches
         Dim objFSO
         Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Test.txt", ForReading)
             Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
                sampletext = objFile.ReadAll
                SearchPattern = "<" 
                SearchPattern = SearchPattern & "(.*?)([\s\S]*?)" 
                SearchPattern = SearchPattern & ">" 
                Set objRegExp = New RegExp
                objRegExp.Pattern = searchpattern ' apply the search pattern
                objRegExp.Global = True ' match all instances if the serach pattern
                objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True ' ignore case 
                Set matches = objRegExp.execute(sampletext)


                    If matches.Count > 0 Then ' there was at least one match to the search pattern  
                        i=0
                        For Each match in matches

                        arrEntry = Split(Split(match.Value, "<")(1), ">")(0)
                        arrFields = Split(arrEntry, vbTab)
                        strTime = arrFields(0)
                        strDate = arrFields(1)
                        strTitle = arrFields(2)
                        strMessage = arrFields(3)

                            strHTML = strHTML & "<p>" & strTime & "</p>"
                            strHTML = strHTML & "<p>" & strDate & "</p>"
                            strHTML = strHTML & "<p>" & strTitle & "</p>"
                            strHTML = strHTML & "<p>" & strMessage & "</p>" 
                            strHTML = strHTML & "<input type='button' name='Delete' value='Delete' >"& i &"<p>"
                        i=i+1
                        Next

                    Else ' there were no matches found
                      MsgBox objRegExp.Pattern & "was not found in the string"
                    End If  
                Loop
        DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
        Set objRegExp = Nothing
        Set objFSO = Nothing
    End Sub



    Sub ClearText
           Title.Value = "" 
           Message.Value = ""
     End Sub

    </SCRIPT>

    <body>
        <input type="text" name="Title" size="101"><p>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="76" type="text" name="Message" size="25"></textarea><p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="SaveData">
        <p><div id="DataArea"></div></p> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you particularly tied to using text files? If you used a database (such as access) you could do this quite easily (you don't have to have access installed to use an access database with an HTA either). And it would open up some other possibilities.

Incidentally, I also notice you're doing this:

```
                        strHTML = strHTML & "<p>" & strTime & "</p>"
                        strHTML = strHTML & "<p>" & strDate & "</p>"
                        strHTML = strHTML & "<p>" & strTitle & "</p>"
                        strHTML = strHTML & "<p>" & strMessage & "</p>"
```

Not a big thing, but concatenating the strings like that isn't great for performance. You'd be better off writing it all to the variable at the same time, otherwise it has to keep writing the variable to memory over and over again.

Comment: Thx for opening my mind to other solution. However, never worked before with databases. Can you provide some examples that shows how to  achieve the same thing with database?

Comment: There's a really good example here that you can pull apart and play with: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-63102.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file with HTA you can easily do it in javaScript. Since the context changes IE allws you to directly read file on the computer or the network to wich the computer is linked to. In order to do so, you need to access the File System Object (FSO)

[Full Documentation on FSO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you are still looking to access a database you need to use the ADODB.Connection. That will allow you to connect to database localy or remotely. Altought there is not much documentation on the subject we did it at my work place. With a little imagination you can figure out how to fix it.

[Documentation on the ADODB.Connnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx)
In this documentation the example are in VB but you can write them in JS as well.